# Adobe Creative Cloud in Wine?

Tags: 14.04, wine, cloud, adobe

Hello once again wonderful people! I'm just wondering if anyone here installed the Adobe Creative Cloud client successfully through wine. If anyone has, I'd really appreciate some help :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you first check the WINE application database?

Comment: Yeah, I did. Apparently it's been tried and it's 'garbage' but honestly I'm desperate and I need it working. I'm new to the whole Wine dealio and need some help with this particular program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP here, I decided 'screw it', and forced Adobe to cancel my creative cloud plan without a fee and bought CS6 from a re-seller. Adobe will never add support for Linux, so there really isn't a point :/